# number of quadruples counting

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

can someone please help me prove the following counting problem.
I have quadruple $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ with distinct $a_i$ and $1\le a_i \le m$ (with m= an odd number greater than equal to 5) for $i=1,2,3,4$.
Question is how many of this quadruple has sum $S = a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4$ such that $m|S$.

Counting the total number of ordered distinct quadruple is easy. It is $m(m-1)(m-2)(m-3)$. But for how many of them the sum $S$ is divisable by $m$ ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean "distinct" $a_i$'s, or $a_i=a_j$ if and only if $i=j$?

Comment: Have you tried solving analogous problems for pairs and/or triples?

Comment: yes i have for pairs and triplets. i think i have some empirical result but cannot prove those results. my results are based on just numerical tinkering

Comment: yes i mean distinct